# 18.04.1 Sources list question

Tags: apt, 18.04, wine

Upgraded to 18.04.1 last night via software updater. Few issues but nothing I can't work out. Question on the bionic sources list though. The source for UbuntuZilla seems to have been disabled and I don't see a replacement added:

```
# deb http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/ubuntuzilla/mozilla/apt all main # disabled on upgrade to bionic
```

Also on the source for wine

```
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main # disabled on upgrade to bionic
```

The reason there is no # in front of the wine source is because I re-enabled it last night. I have wine installed however it was under 16.04. Running wine --version shows

```
wine --version
wine-3.13
```

However apt-cache policy wine-stable disagrees

```
apt-cache policy wine-stable
wine-stable:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.0.2~bionic
  Version table:
 3.0.2~bionic 500
    500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
 3.0.1~bionic 500
    500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
 3.0-1ubuntu1 500
    500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
    500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
```

Would it be advisable to run 'sudo apt install wine-stable' then?

Comment: This page https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu explains how to use the wine-builds repo. It appears that if you want to use that repo, you'll have to choose between winehq-stable, winehq-devel, and winehq-staging.  I personally just use wine-stable from the default repos since I don't need the bleeding edge.  3.0 is a lot better than the version that was in 14.04 which I upgraded from!

Comment: The link shows the same repo as I have in my sources. I'm curious though as to why it shows this - # disabled on upgrade to bionic

Comment: When you run a upgrade, one of the first things that happens is that the 3rd party repos get disabled.

Comment: The update to wine-stable worked fine. I assume then that when you said above that 3rd party repos get disabled then the thing to do is to re-enable the http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/ubuntuzilla/mozilla/apt all main repo.

Comment: As long as a version of it exists for `bionic`, that should be OK.

Comment: apt-cache policy firefox
firefox:
  Installed: 61.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
  Candidate: 61.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
The Bionic version was installed on the upgrade so I'll go in and enable that repo again. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: am having this for even apt-get